# hidepage and onbeforeunload not functioning on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, mobile, web-applications

What I am trying to achieve is when my web page is closed/refresh, it will send a post request to update some data.

To do this, I listen to 'hidepage', 'onbeforeunload' events, and it works perfectly on PC. However, it dosen't work on both IOS and Android.

If anyone have the solution/suggestion please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code?